# Why is glMapBuffer returning NULL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm not trying to stream or anything, I just want to speed up my file loading code by loading vertex and index data directly into OpenGL's buffer instead of having to put it in an intermediate buffer first. Here's the code that grabs the pointer:

```
void* VertexArray::beginIndexLoad(GLenum indexFormat, unsigned int indexCount)
{
    if (vao == 0)
        return NULL;

    bindArray();

    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexSize(indexFormat) * indexCount, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    iformat = indexFormat;
    icount = indexCount;

    GLenum err = glGetError();
    printf("%i\n", err);

    void* ptr = glMapBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);

    err = glGetError();
    printf("%i\n", err);

    unbindArray();

    return ptr;
}
```

Problem is, this returns NULL. What's worse, just before I do something similar with `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, and I get a perfectly valid pointer. Why does this fail, while the other succeeds?

The first `glGetError` returns 1280 (`GL_INVALID_ENUM`).  The second glGetError returns 1285(`GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY`).  I know it's not actually out of memory because uploading the exact same data normally via `glBufferData` works fine.

Maybe I'm just handling vertex arrays wrong?

(ps. I asked this on gamedev stack exchange and got nothing.  Re-posting here to try to figure it out)

Comment: you need glBindVertexArrayOES(0);, it has to be 0. That how it works for me. Just bind buffer laster glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost your error checking code is wrong. You must call `glGetError` in a loop until it returns `GL_NO_ERROR`.

Regarding the `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error code: It can also mean *out of address space*, which can easily happen if a large contiguous area of virtual address space is requested from the OS, but the process' address space is so much fragmented that no chunk that size is available (even if the total amount of free address space would suffice).

This has become the bane of 32 bit systems. A simple remedy is to use a 64 bit system. If you're stuck with a 32 bit plattform you'll have to defragment your address space (which is not trivial).

Comment: Okay, I've flushed `glGetError` before calling either `beginVertexLoad` or `beginIndexLoad`.  Now, the first `glGetError` returns 0, but the second one still gives me 1285 (`GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY`).  `beginVertexLoad` still works fine and still returns a valid pointer.

I'd like to stick to 32-bit for the sake of compatability.  I'm not using any memory management so defragmenting my address space is impossible.

I don't even see how my memory could become fragmented, I'm literally only importing the one mesh.  All the application does at this point is load the model and give you a camera to see it

Comment: @HaydnV.Harach: It's a far call, but what's in that `bindArray` function you call at the beginning. Something done in there might prevent a successful mapping.

Comment: bindArray is a simple inline helper function that wraps glBindVertexArray().  Here's what it does: `if (boundArray == vao) return; glBindVertexArray(0); glBindVertexArray(vao); boundArray = vao;`

Comment: @HaydnV.Harach: I'm not 100% sure about this (I've to read into the specification first), but IIRC you can not map a buffer object while it's being bound for access with a VAO (without VAOs while having a VBO mapped trying to render from it would result in an invalid operation error). Anyway, you don't need the VAO being bound while operating on the contents of the VBO, so I suggest you just call `unbindArray` at the begin (instead of `bindArray`). Binding the VAO is required for associating a VBO with a vertex attribute and for drawing operations of data in the VAO/VBO.

Comment: I tried what you suggested (unbind instead of bind) but it didn't work, I still get NULL.  The VAO is bound when I glMapBuffer the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, and the pointer I get from that is valid, so I don't think that's the issue...

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would try the following:

- Replace `GL_STATIC_DRAW` with `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW`
- Make sure that `indexSize(indexFormat) * indexCount` produces the size you are expecting
- Try using `glMapBufferRange` instead of `glMapBuffer`, something along the line of `glMapBufferRange(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, yourBufferSize, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT);`
- Check that `ibo` is of type `GLuint`

EDIT: fwiw, I would get a gDEBugger and set a breakpoint to break when there is  an OpenGL error.

Comment: I tried replacing `GL_STATIC_DRAW` with `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` to no avail.  I also tried `glMapBufferRange` instead of `glMapBuffer`, also to no avail.  I know that `indexSize(indexFormat) * indexCount` produces correct results, because when I upload the data the normal way it works fine.  `ibo` is of type `unsigned int`, but I know it works because it does elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.  I was passing in `indexSize(header.indexFormat)` when I should have been passing in `header.indexFormat`.  I feel like an idiot now, and I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time.