# GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER memory limitations

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm writing ray-tracing on OGL computing shaders, to pass data to and from shaders I use buffers.

When size of vec2 output buffer (which is equal to number of rays multiplied by number of faces) reaches ~30Mb attempt of mapping buffer is stable returning NULL pointer. Range mapping also fails.

I can't find any info about GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER limitations in ogl documentation, but maybe someone can help me, is ~30Mb limit or this mapping-fail may happen because of something different?

And is there any way to avoid this except for calling shader multiple times?

Data declaration in shader:

```
#version 440
layout(std430, binding=0) buffer rays{
    vec4 r[];
};
layout(std430, binding=1) buffer faces{
    vec4 f[];
};
layout(std430, binding=2) buffer outputs{
    vec2 o[];
};
uniform int face_count;
uniform vec4 origin;
```

Calling code (using some Qt5 wrappers):

```
QOpenGLBuffer ray_buffer;
QOpenGLBuffer face_buffer;
QOpenGLBuffer output_buffer;

QVector<QVector2D> output;

output.resize(rays[r].size()*faces.size());

if(!ray_buffer.create()) { /*...*/ }
if(!ray_buffer.bind()) { /*...*/ }
ray_buffer.allocate(rays.data(), rays.size()*sizeof(QVector4D));

if(!face_buffer.create()) { /*...*/ }
if(!face_buffer.bind()) { /*...*/ }
face_buffer.allocate(faces.data(), faces.size()*sizeof(QVector4D));

if(!output_buffer.create()) { /*...*/ }
if(!output_buffer.bind()) { /*...*/ }

output_buffer.allocate(output.size()*sizeof(QVector2D));

ogl->glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, ray_buffer.bufferId());
ogl->glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, face_buffer.bufferId());
ogl->glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 2, output_buffer.bufferId());

int face_count = faces.size();

compute.setUniformValue("face_count", face_count);
compute.setUniformValue("origin", pos);

ogl->glDispatchCompute(rays.size()/256, faces.size(), 1);

ray_buffer.destroy();
face_buffer.destroy();
QVector2D* data = (QVector2D*)output_buffer.map(QOpenGLBuffer::ReadOnly);
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to understand that the OpenGL specification defines *minimum maxima* for a variety of values (the ones starting with a `MAX_{*}` prefix). That means that implementations are required to *at least* provide the specified amount as the maximum value, but are free to increase the limit as implementors see fit. This way, developers can at least rely on some upper bound, but can still make provisions for possibly larger values.

**Section 23 - State Tables** summarizes what has been previously specified in the corresponding sections. The information you were looking for is found in table **23.64 - Implementation Dependent Aggregate Shader Limits (cont.)**. If you want to know about which state belongs where (because there is per-object state, quasi-global state, program state and so on), you go to section 23.

---

The *minimum* maximum size of a shader storage buffer is represented by the symbolic constant `MAX_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK_SIZE` as per section **7.8** of the [core **OpenGL 4.5** specification](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf).

Since their adoption into core, the required size (i.e. the minimum maximum) has been significantly increased. In core OpenGL 4.3 and 4.4, the minimum maximum was `pow(2, 24)` (or 16MB with 1 byte basic machine units and 1MB = 1024^2 bytes) - in core OpenGL 4.5 this value is now `pow(2, 27)` (or 128MB)

---

**Summary**: When in doubt about OpenGL state, refer to **section 23** of the core specification.

Comment: Hmmm. When I request MAX_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK_SIZE I get value of 2Gb, I've changed version of OpenGL to 4.5 but still my program fails to read data, when buffer is around 30Mb. What else can cause such behavior?

Comment: Oh, you mean the read-back after mapping? Can you successfully allocate and use a shader storage buffer with the size you require?

Comment: @CrazySage can you try to use [`glMapBufferRange`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glMapBufferRange.xml) directly? I think Qt defaults the buffer target type to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`(and there is no 4.x types in [enum](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglbuffer.html#Type-enum)). Try calling it with `GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER` as target (and ensure that buffer is correctly bound)

Comment: @CrazySage: Alternatively, you could try `glMapNamedBuffer` which is target-independent (i.e. is either inferred from object state or irrelevant). You can use `QGLBuffer::bufferId()` to get the buffer object name.

Comment: @thokra, I did some additional testing. Allocating buffer is ok, at least there is GL_NO_ERROR after it. And mapping leads to out of memory error, glMapNamedBuffer instead of Qt wrap didn't made any difference.

Comment: @CrazySage: Regarding `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY`: "This may occur for a variety of system-specific reasons, such as the absence of sufficient remaining virtual memory." Simply put, if you don't have sufficient address space to map to, you'll ne be able to map the whole buffer. Either try to map a sequence of buffer ranges or go for a persistent buffer mapping. The latter should fail at allocation time when not enough memory is available. Also, for your read-back scenario a persistent mapping might prove beneficial anyway.

Comment: @thokra mapping buffer range fails as well, so I don't think it's address space problem. As for persistend mapping - never heard of it before, thanks for directions, I'll try it.

Comment: @CrazySage: Mapping a buffer range to an insufficient range of system memory results in the same problem. Say you have 16 MB of memory you can map *to*, but you have 32MB of memory you want to map *from*. If you map the buffer as whole, it will probably fail, but if you map two 16MB ranges or even four 8MB ranges sequentially, iit will most likely succeed. BTW, are you building a 32-bit application? Also, read datenwolfs answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156975/why-is-glmapbuffer-returning-null).

Comment: @thokra I tried mapping around 30kb instead of 30Mb with map range and still got out of memory error, so I really don't think that there is insufficient memory problem. Anyway, 20-25Mb buffer is mapping ok, and 30Mb is failing to map absolutely stable, as first iteration of loop, as not-first and so on. And yes, currently I'm building 32-bit app.

Answer (score 2):

From [OpenGL Wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object):

> SSBOs can be much larger. The OpenGL spec guarantees that UBOs can be
>   up to 16KB in size (implementations can allow them to be bigger). The
>   spec guarantees that SSBOs can be up to 128MB. Most implementations
>   will let you allocate a size up to the limit of GPU memory.

OpenGL < 4.5 guarantees only `16MiB` (OpenGL 4.5 increased the minimum to `128MiB`) , you can try using `glGet()` to query if you can bind more.

```
GLint64 max;
glGetInteger64v(GL_MAX_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK_SIZE, &max);
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact problem seems to be in Qt wrappers. Didn't look in-depth, but when I've changed QOpenGLBuffer's create(), bind(), allocate() and map() to glCreateBuffers(), glBindBuffer(), glNamedBufferData() and glMapNamedBuffer(), all called through QOpenGLFunctions_4_5_Core, memory problem was gone until I reached 2Gb (which is GPU physical memory limit).

Second error I've made was not using glMemoryBarrier(), but it didn't help while QOpenGLBuffer was in use.